# Link to Source data does still NOT work on OSX! - VBA workaround issues

Tags: excel, vba, macos

In management having and updating a deck of 150 slides is hard, when automation does not work. On Windows you can easily update numbers in Excel and Connected Graphs (Link to source data) change.

I don't know if anyone wondered, but it seems a long known issue:

To paint on the picture, to make clear what I want to achieve with my coding, here the rest of the story: In our company, there are coming all kind of systems together. I am using a Mac (and Office Mac), while others request the same data and working it with Office Windows. As I found out its the Apple system's arangement that disable many functions of MSO Programms or automation. I tested this automatic update story with a Office on Windows and Mac and did the following steps:

1. Created an Excel file and put in some numbers
2. Made a graph from that.
3. "Special-pasted" the graph in a new Powerpoint file (with link to data source - no here is not a mistake)
4. Changed numbers in Excel and it updated the graph in Powerpoint.
5. Saved and closed both files in one folder. (and did not change the path of course)
6. Opened the Excel again, changed data and opened Powerpoint (comparing Office Windows and Office Mac)

   - Office Windows: Powerpoint asked me to update all linked data. Data updated
   - Office Mac: did not ask anything. Data not updated.

So this is only the description of the bigger problem. To solve that issue (that may only be fixed in years... its been a long known issue already) I am trying to use VBA.

In the code I differenciate between Windows and Mac, finally there should be one code for all users. What I did so far:

1. run a code depending on the operating system (Mac is the problem!!)
2. copy range
3. create chart
4. paste range into chart
5. save chart as image

--> here I have problems, as saved files on Mac are empty (0 bytes).

NOTE: My example excel is hold easy and contains 3 sheets: UKI, France and Pictures. UKI and France are example sheets with numbers and graphs, created from those. The graphs' range is copied and used to copy - one by one - into pictures. The aim is to copy a chart, save it - and repeat this for each country area (eg. UKI France).

Where I am struggling is the export part. On Mac files normally are saved in a special microsoft folder ..../users/.../microsoft.com/data/......

When I try to adress "special folders"; such as desktop, pictures, documents (etc.) I receive an error message saying "permission denied". Here the Apple Sandbox Requirements seem to block me off.
Only the special folder "pictures" seem to work: saved files appear, but just like in the microsoft folder they are created empty.

I am new to VBA, so this i probably a mess of a code -
but why are the saved jpg/jpeg. files empty (also other picture-formats are empty)??

My Coding so far: (May be out of position a bit)

---

```
Sub TakePictures()
'check for running system; then play script for Mac or Windows

    #If Mac Then
    'I am a Mac
        MsgBox "Call your Mac_Macro"

        MsgBox "Call your Mac_Macro"
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim intCount As Integer
        Dim objPic As Shape
        Dim objChart As Chart

        'UKI

        'copy the range as an image
        Call Worksheets("UKI").Range("D1:I14").CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)

        'remove all previous shapes in sheet2
        intCount = Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Count
        For i = 1 To intCount
        Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Delete
        Next i
        'create an empty chart in sheet2
        Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.AddChart
        'activate sheet2
        Worksheets("Picture").Activate
        'select the shape in sheet2
        Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Select
        Set objChart = ActiveChart

        'paste the range into the chart

        Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Line.Visible = msoFalse
        Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Width = Range("D1:I14").Width
        Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Height = Range("D1:I14").Height
        objChart.Paste


        ' Call AppleScript to get a special folder
        Dim NameFolder As String
        Dim SpecialFolder As String

        ' You can use : home, documents, desktop, music, pictures, movies, applications
        NameFolder = "documents"

        If Int(Val(Application.Version)) > 14 Then
              SpecialFolder = _
              MacScript("return POSIX path of (path to " & NameFolder & " folder) as string")
              'Replace line needed for the special folders Home and documents
              SpecialFolder = _
              Replace(SpecialFolder, "/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data", "")
              Else
              SpecialFolder = MacScript("return (path to " & NameFolder & " folder) as string")
        End If


        Dim fileAccessGranted As Boolean
        Dim filePermissionCandidates
        'Create an array with file paths for which permissions are needed_
        'filePermissionCandidates = Array("/Users/<user>/Desktop/test1.txt", "/Users/<user>/Desktop.  /test2.txt")

        'Request Access from User_
        'fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates)

        'save the chart as a JPEG
        Dim LoginName As String
        LoginName = UCase(GetUserID)

        'ChDir "C:\Users\" & LoginName & "\Specialfolder"\"

        Debug.Print LoginName
        'objChart.Export ("C:Users\" & LoginName & "\documents\FY1718_UKI.jpg")

        objChart.Export ("/Users/fabianvoss/pictures/FY1718_UKI.pdf")


'*here the export does give me empty files - tested out already all different kind of different data types.

    #Else
    'I am Windows
        MsgBox "Call Windows_Macro"
            'Activeselection.Export Filename:="D:\FY1718_UKI.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
            'Existiert Bild-Ordner unter Laufwerk C? -> Abfrage mit if:
            'Wenn ja: Weiter
            'Sonst: erstellen, dann weiter
            On Error Resume Next
            MkDir "C:\VBATestBilder"
            On Error GoTo 0
            'Neues Sheet erstellen: "Picture"
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim intCount As Integer
            Dim objPic As Shape
            Dim objChart As Chart


            'UKI

            'copy the range as an image
            Call Worksheets("UKI").Range("D1:I14").CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)

            'remove all previous shapes in sheet2
            intCount = Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Count
            For i = 1 To intCount
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Delete
            Next i
            'create an empty chart in sheet2
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.AddChart
            'activate sheet2
            Worksheets("Picture").Activate
            'select the shape in sheet2
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Select
            Set objChart = ActiveChart
            'paste the range into the chart

            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Line.Visible = msoFalse
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Width = Range("D1:I14").Width
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Height = Range("D1:I14").Height
            objChart.Paste
            'save the chart as a JPEG
            objChart.Export ("C:\VBATestBilder\FY1718_UKI.Jpeg")



            'FRANCE

            'copy the range as an image
            Call Worksheets("France").Range("D1:I14").CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)

            'remove all previous shapes in sheet2
            intCount = Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Count
            For i = 1 To intCount
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Delete
            Next i
            'create an empty chart in sheet2
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.AddChart
            'activate sheet2
            Worksheets("Picture").Activate
            'select the shape in sheet2
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Select
            Set objChart = ActiveChart
            'paste the range into the chart

            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Line.Visible = msoFalse
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Width = Range("D1:I14").Width
            Worksheets("Picture").Shapes.Item(1).Height = Range("D1:I14").Height
            objChart.Paste
            'save the chart as a JPEG
            objChart.Export ("C:\VBATestBilder\FY1718_France.Jpeg")
            'Delete new chart


    #End If
End Sub
```

I dont get why the files on Mac are created but empty... ?

(Then, if files can be saved, I need to import them to Powerpoint to very different positions on different slides (on Windows its easy, on Mac maybe difficult))

Thank you for reading, 
I would appreciate any help

PS: I am completely new to VBA

regards,
Fabian

Comment: Your question looks quite extensive, any possibility that you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes basically I look for a VBA workaround for linked data on MAC systems, as link to source data-connections for pasted graphics from excel to powerpoint break on MAC.

The coding should be able to automate and unify the updating of excel data in connected powerpoint graphics for Mac and Windows systems.

What I thought of:
1. Differenciate between systems (for mac different code is needed)
2. Copy graphics as images
(2.1 save locally)
3. Upload to specific Powerpoint slides
4. repeat same for "different countries"